# Node.js and Couchbase Compatibility

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am attempting to install the Node.js SDK for Couchbase on a Windows 7 machine.     I am running the installation by typing `npm install --save couchbase` into a command prompt window.  I have received mixed results from my attempts.  My results are below.

Versions for Which the Installation Works Well

- 0.10.40
- 0.10.45
- 0.12.14

Versions for Which the Installation Generates Multiple Compilation Errors

- 4.0.0
- 4.3.0
- 4.4.5
- 5.6.0
- 6.2.0

Do you know with which versions of Node.js the Node SDK for Couchbase is compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several potential solutions, I have been able to get the Node.js SDK for Couchbase to install on my machine over Node.js 6.0.0.  I am sharing the information below, in case anyone else is experiencing the same issue.  These steps seem to have resolved the problem for me.

1. Uninstalled Visual Studio 2012 (and Visual Studio 2015...I attempted to use both versions to no avail)
2. Restarted my computer
3. Installed all of the components (not just the defaults) for Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)
4. Restarted my computer
5. Opened a command prompt and made sure NVM was using Node.js 6.0.0 (e.g. `nvm use 6.0.0` or `nvm install 6.0.0`)
6. From the command prompt, globally installed node-gyp (npm install –g node-gyp) (Reference:  https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)
7. From the command prompt, ran `npm config set msvs_version=2013`
8. From the command prompt, ran `npm config get msvs_version` to confirm that I got 2013 by setting the value in the previous step
9. From the command prompt, ran `npm config set python <path_to_the_python_executable>` e.g. `npm config set c:\Python27\python.exe`
10. Ran `npm config get python` to confirm that I got the value I typed in the previous step
11. From the command prompt, ran `npm install couchbase`

Some additional information is available in [this thread](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/node-js-sdk-installation-on-windows/8655) on the Couchbase forum.

Comment: Are Python and Visual Studio really necessary?

Comment: @cricket_007 My understanding is that node-gyp, the package that compiles the couchbase package on your computer, relies on both Visual Studio and Python.  According to the "Installation" section of the node-gyp package's [Github page](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp), you can use the [Visual C++ Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) instead of Visual Studio.  If you are able to install the couchbase package without Python, then please let me know.